# Assistance needed with Java GUI working with ODFDOM

Tags: java, swing, odftoolkit, odfdom

Ok, so as a little personal programming project I had been trying to make a program in the past which would (via a GUI) held to record data of item drops from certain stuff in a game (Guild Wars 2 if you're curious). The GUI is simple enough: `JFrame` containing two `JLabels` and `JTextFields`, to say what to input and well, the text fields to type it in. Basic GUI stuff. The inputs are the item name and the amount. Also, there are two `JButtons`, with a listener each to add items and subtract items and finally another `JLabel` to function as error message display.

The structure of the "mapping" of items to amount obtained is stored during the execution of the java program in a `TreeMap`.

I had been creating a crude, basic implemention, saving data to memory in a .csv file but I decided last night I wanted to rework the system. Thus, I got the idea of trying to "write" to a spreadsheet format, and I thought, "well why not OpenOffice? Consequently, I discovered the ODFToolkit API and such, specifically the ODFDOM tools have been of interest to me of course. So I had thought I had this stuff refactored (if that's the right term) well enough and that things would go smoothly but...here's my problem:

So, in the GUI I type some test input; "Rotten Egg" is a valid item (invalids make an error display in the window) and I put some positive integer (only possibly type of valid "amount") for the amount obtained. Now, the first time I do this, with a valid input like this it works fine, but if I try again with different input or the same it displays the error text that should show only when an invalid item is entered. I tried a few things at least to debug it looking through it, but I am at a loss as to how this horrible bug has been created.

I will link to pastebin for my own two classes here:
GUI class: http://pastebin.com/rEbFS27j
Other class i.e. the `Map` structure and other stuff going on "behind" the GUI: http://pastebin.com/BWA4SUY0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*sigh* I figured it out eventually. I have this loop in the method that writes to the spreadsheet.

```
while (it.hasNext() == true) {
            Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();

            odt.getTableList().get(0).getCellByPosition("A" + i).setDisplayText((String) pairs.getKey()) ;
            odt.getTableList().get(0).getCellByPosition("B" + i).setDisplayText((pairs.getValue().toString())) ;
            it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
            i++ ;
            }
```

The line `it.remove()` ("it" is an Iterator variable) is a fatal error...an unfortunate remnant from a copy-paste when I looked up stuff in the past about how to use iterators... :/ Indeed it was the cause of this horrid "only works once" kind of bug. Guess I just really need to make sure I'm not using something wrong or unnecessary when I paste snippets of someone else's code into my work...